# Is it true that if $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus C \subseteq (C \Delta A) \cup (B \setminus A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that if $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus C \subseteq (C \Delta  A) \cup (B \setminus A)$?

I tried verifying this with Venn diagrams, and it looks true, but I couldn't prove it.

This is my attempt, but as you can see I didn't get nothing useful :(

$x \in B \setminus C \implies x \in B $ and $ x \notin C \implies x \in B \cup A$ and $x \in C^C \cup A$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it by element-chasing.

Suppose that $x\in B\setminus C$; then $x\in B$, and $x\notin C$. Now either $x\in A$, or $x\notin A$. If $x\notin A$, then $x\in B\setminus A\subseteq(C\mathop{\triangle}A)\cup(B\setminus A)$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\setminus C$, so $x\in C\mathop{\triangle}A\subseteq(C\mathop{\triangle}A)\cup(B\setminus A)$. Thus, in every case $x\in(C\mathop{\triangle}A)\cup(B\setminus A)$, and therefore $$B\setminus C\subseteq(C\mathop{\triangle}A)\cup(B\setminus A)\,.$$